# tinyMCE losing frame in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, tinymce

I have a web-site.  We are using TinyMCE as our text editor.  I just upgraded to the newest version and added the media plugin so our users can add videos to their enteries.
The upgrade works great on Chrome, FireFox, IE7.  However, it does not work with IE8.  The frame around the editor disappears along with the toolbar.

Here is the init code I'm using:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options

    mode : 'exact',
    elements : '<%= txtArea.ClientID %>',
    theme: 'advanced',
    relative_urls : false,
    verify_html : true,
    apply_source_formatting : true,
    plugins : 'media',
    //valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank],#p[align],strong/b,em/i,u,div,br,-span[style],' 
    //            <%= AllowImages ? "+ 'img[longdesc|usemap|src|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align],'" : "" %>
    //    + '-ul,-ol,-li',
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,underline,separator,link,unlink,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,'
        <%= AllowImages ? "+ 'separator,image,'" : "" %> + 'separator,code,media',
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : '',
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : '' 
});
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Feeling like a complete dork now.  Internet Explorer cahce's like a mofo so what was happening was the result of caching inside IE.  There are two solutions to this problem: have users clear their cache local (yeah right like that is happening) or add the data & time to the end of your query strings to guarantee that IE won't find the data in its cache.  I'm going to go sit in the corner now.

Comment: you should post it as an answer, I think this is pretty useful info :P

Answer (score 0):

Jake raised a point in the comments that this was a caching related issue.

As suggested in the comment, options to work around include clearing cache and including a date/time query string.

I'd suggest a third option to the above -- including the version number of the component being used in the url (either put tinymce in a version specific folder, or put the version number in the query string).